# Extrair nome e ultimo sobrenome mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia Pessoal, como extraio o nome e o ultimo sobrenome de um registro. Porém o mesmo deve retornar o nome e sobrenome quanto tiver um sobrenome apenas. Minha tabela está assim.

> table = 'users'; 
> campo1 = 'nome';
>   campo2 = 'sobronome';

Nome: Eduardo da Silva Fernandes

Gostaria de extrair assim: 'Eduardo Fernandes';

Eu fiz isso aqui, porém só funciona para os registros que contenham 2 sobrenomes.

```
$separar = explode(' ', $reg['nome'] . '.&nbsp;.' . $reg['sobrenome']);
            $primeiroNome = array_shift($separar);
            $ultimoNome = array_pop($separar);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se quiser extrair logo diretamente da base de dados com `SQL`:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(coluna_nome, ' ', 1) as nome, SUBSTRING_INDEX(coluna_nome, ' ', -1) as sobrenome from tabela_pessoas;
```

Mas pelo que mostrou SQL nem entra aí, para fazer com `php`:

```
$nome_todo = 'Eduardo da Silva Fernandes';
$nomes = explode(' ', $nome_todo); // separamos por espaços e fica: Array ( [0] => Eduardo [1] => da [2] => Silva [3] => Fernandes )
$nome = $nomes[0]; // primeiro nome
$sobrenome = $nomes[count($nomes) - 1]; // ultimo nome, total de nomes - 1 que é o ultimo elemento de $nomes

echo $nome; // Eduardo
echo $sobrenome; // Fernandes
```

Contudo, se quiser fazer isto para vários utilizadores pode (e deve) construir uma função para não estar a repetir código:

```
function nome_sobrenome($nome_todo) {
    $nomes = explode(' ', $nome_todo);
    if(count($nomes) === 1) { // caso alguém tenha um só nome
        return $nomes[0];
    }
    return $nomes[0]. ' ' .$nomes[count($nomes) - 1];
}

$eduardo = nome_sobrenome('Eduardo da Silva Fernandes'); // Eduardo Fernandes
$maria = nome_sobrenome('Maria dos Santos Anacleto Constantina'); // Maria Constantina
$adriana = nome_sobrenome('Adriana Lima'); // Adriana Lima
$miguel = nome_sobrenome('Miguel'); // Miguel
```

Comment: Muito bom cara. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Tranquilo, ainda bem que ajudei

Comment: Excelente dica, me ajudou muito em um projeto aqui, grande abraço.