# Preciso pegar a ultima string mas ele consta espaço como remover o espaço final?

Tags: sql

```
select 
    top 1 SUBSTRING(
       [nome funcionario],
       CHARINDEX(' ',[nome funcionario]),
       LEN([nome funcionario])
    ) 
as Sobrenome 
from Tabela_nome
```

Resultados
" DE FREITAS  "

O problema é que ele consta espaço no inicio do sobrenome e no final do sobrenome, como remover espaço e trazer apenas "DE FREITAS"

Comment: Benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Tentou a função `TRIM`?

Comment: Trim e caso como "de freitas" precisariam ser tratados. Regornaria "freitas".

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131877/extrair-nome-e-ultimo-sobrenome-mysql

Answer (score 0):

Apenas use TRIM(string) na sua query, igual o Daniel Ikenaga falou.
Deixarei alguns exemplos que encontrei:

```sql
SELECT TRIM(leading ' ' from ' Google.com ');

--Result: 'Google.com '

SELECT TRIM(trailing ' ' from ' Google.com ');

--Result: '' Google.com'

SELECT TRIM(both ' ' from ' Google.com ');

--Result: 'Google.com'

SELECT TRIM(' ' from ' Google.com ');

--Result: 'Google.com'

SELECT trim(' Google.com ');

--Result: 'Google.com'

SELECT trim(leading '0' from '000123');

--Result: '123'

SELECT TRIM(trailing '1' from 'Number1');

--Result: 'Number'

SELECT TRIM(both '123' from '123PostgreSQL123');

--Result: 'PostgreSQL'
```

Caso queria saber mais, clique [aqui](https://www.sqlsplus.com/postgresql-trim-function/) (inglês, mas com certeza tem em pt-br) para ver o site que peguei de referência.

Mas claro, mesmo existindo essa função no sql, você pode fazer essa alteração no próprio código, vamos a um exemplo em python:

```py
s1 = '  abc  '

print(f'String =\'{s1}\'')

print(f'Depois de remover espaços em branco da ESQUERDA da string =\'{s1.lstrip()}\'')

print(f'Depois de remover espaços em branco da DIREITA da string =\'{s1.rstrip()}\'')

print(f'Depois de remover espaços em branco da ESQUERDA E DIREITA da string =\'{s1.strip()}\'')
```

resultado:

```
String ='  abc  '
Depois de remover espaços em branco da ESQUERDA da string ='abc  '
Depois de remover espaços em branco da DIREITA da string  ='  abc'
Depois de remover espaços em branco da ESQUERDA E DIREITA da string ='abc'
```

Para saber mais aprofundadamente, leia [aqui](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/python-trim-string-rstrip-lstrip-strip) (inglês, mas com certeza tem em pt-br)